# I want to exclude specific words from the results when piping tail into grep

Tags: grep, tail, exclude

I am using "tail -f /var/log/fail2ban.log -f /var/log/ufw.log | grep -e Ban -e BLOCK -e ALLOW" (without the quotes) and it is working but I want to exclude the results that have the words UDP and ICMP in them. When I try "tail -f /var/log/fail2ban.log -f /var/log/ufw.log | grep -e Ban -e BLOCK -e ALLOW -v UDP -v ICMP" I get an error "grep: UDP: No such file or directory" It seems as though using -v to exclude words does not work when piping.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2boLZ.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

You can just pipe the first output to another grep and use it as another "filter" like:

```
tail -f /var/log/fail2ban.log -f /var/log/ufw.log | grep "Ban\|BLOCK\|ALLOW" | grep -v "UDP\|ICMP"
```

Note that grep can stack different strings even regex when you use double quotes separating it by a pipe "|" but you should scape the character with "\" to not get weird things.

The -v parameter literally says in man

> -v, --invert-match
> Invert the sense of matching, to select non-matching lines.

So it seems to just invert the match you determine, so you cannot parametrize it.

Like in you see in the synopsis you can give 3 types of parameters.
Options, a pattern and a file.

Options are a whole always start with - or -- and you can put a bunch of them.

You can determine a single pattern or a specific type of pattern with -e or -f or withouth anithing.

And always the last should be the file/s or directory (Directories needs -R parameter to recurse them or you can just put directory/*). if not specified it will try to read the stdin like you are doing.

```
   SYNOPSIS
   grep [OPTION...] PATTERNS [FILE...]
   grep [OPTION...] -e PATTERNS ... [FILE...]
   grep [OPTION...] -f PATTERN_FILE ... [FILE...]
```

Anyway this is already [answered](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4538253/how-can-i-exclude-one-word-with-grep) in a more basic way

Comment: Your solution makes sense, it's logical and reasonable but when I tried it I got no results and no error. Just a prompt.

Comment: Then you should check if you really aren't getting desired matches and adjust the filter.

Answer (score 0):

I have a work-around for this using 2 ssh sessions I pipe the results of the first grep statement into a file and then in the 2nd ssh session I tail the results piped into grep.  (1st ssh session) - tail -f /var/log/fail2ban.log -f /var/log/ufw.log | grep -v ICMP >/home/user/staging (2nd ssh session) - tail -f /home/user/staging | grep -e ALLOW -e BLOCK a bit unconventional but it works.

Comment: Please add further details to expand on your answer, such as working code or documentation citations.